# PHP Documentor - creating or modifying Templates

Tags: php, phpdoc

i am using PHP Documentor for the first time.

I need to know how i can change the html generated by the parser in a way that i can integrate this documentation within my company's framework.

Has anyone ever did this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend to check out [DocBlox](http://www.docblox-project.org/) instead. It is a modern version of PHPDocumentor with support for PHP 5.3 features. Much faster and more memory efficient.

Building your own template is easy -- see [docs](http://docs.docblox-project.org/Building%20your%20own%20branding.html).

Comment: thanks, i will look around. can you tell me if the docblocks i used already are going to be changed, and if so, if it's going to be a lot of work?

Comment: It will be easy! DocBlox is pretty much a drop in replacement for PHPDocumentor

Comment: thanks again. i am having some trouble though, running it on windows. I installed it through PEAR and i can't seem to run it like they say on http://docs.docblox-project.org/Installation.html#manual-installation

Answer (score 1):

According to the [PHP Documentor feature list](http://www.phpdoc.org/features.php), output can be supplied in the following formats: HTML, PDF (directly), CHM (with windows help compiler), XML DocBook.

Additionally, all output can be customized with Smarty templates.

Please see the [documentation](http://manual.phpdoc.org/) for specific instructions.

Comment: Nevertheless, it is the right answer for the asked question. If you wish to modify the output of PHP Documentor to match your proposed structure, the docs provide the roadmap.